# Cannot call value of non-function type 'SwipeCard' in the function error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I am currently trying to implement a cocoa pod, but when using it I get the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'SwipeCard'" in the function " func cardStack". It may a silly mistake since I am just learning how to code in swift.

```
import UIKit
import Shuffle

class CardsViewViewController: UIViewController, SwipeCardStackDataSource {
    
    let card = SwipeCard()
    
    let cardStack = SwipeCardStack()
    
    let cardImages = [
        UIImage(named: "cardImage1"),
        UIImage(named: "cardImage2"),
        UIImage(named: "cardImage3")
    ]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
              view.addSubview(cardStack)
              cardStack.frame = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
        
                cardStack.dataSource = self
          }
    
    func cardStack(_ cardStack: SwipeCardStack, cardForIndexAt index: Int) -> SwipeCard {
      return card(fromImage: cardImages[index])
    }

    func numberOfCards(in cardStack: SwipeCardStack) -> Int {
      return cardImages.count
    }
}
```

There is a function included in the package as well, but according to the installation guide, this is what I am supposed to do (but I opted to just implement card = SwipeCard() instead of putting the whole function):

1 -Create your own card by either subclassing SwipeCard or setting its properties directly:

```
func card(fromImage image: UIImage) -> SwipeCard {
  let card = SwipeCard()
  card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right]
  card.content = UIImageView(image: image)
  
  let leftOverlay = UIView()
  leftoverlay.backgroundColor = .green
  
  let rightOverlay = UIView()
  rightOverlay.backgroundColor = .red
  
  card.setOverlays([.left: leftOverlay, .right: rightOverlay])
  
  return card
}
```

2 - The card returned from card(fromImage:) displays an image, can be swiped left or right, and has overlay views for both directions.

What am I getting wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove `let card = SwipeCard()` and leaving just the following function:

```
func card(fromImage image: UIImage) -> SwipeCard {
  let card = SwipeCard()
  card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right]
  card.content = UIImageView(image: image)
  let leftOverlay = UIView()
  leftoverlay.backgroundColor = .green
  let rightOverlay = UIView()
  rightOverlay.backgroundColor = .red
  card.setOverlays([.left: leftOverlay, .right: rightOverlay])
  return card
}
```

which is basically the one you call inside

```
 func cardStack(_ cardStack: SwipeCardStack, cardForIndexAt index: Int) -> SwipeCard
```

The error is telling you that you are trying to call a `SwipeCard` instance instead of a method.

I think you are referring to the constant `let card` rather than the function inside the above function.